# Japanese Language Pack

Tags: multi-language, language

I've checked the existing Language Packs for ExpressionEngine and to no avail there is none for Japanese. Does anyone know where I can get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you can find these things on Github. I found one: https://github.com/nicolasbottari/japanese.ee2_language_pack

Comment: thanks, you saved me time but mostly my life :)